# R: How to store date in a data.frame and prevent R from converting it to numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

```
mydat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2), date_of_entry = c(NA, NA, NA))
mydate <- structure(17189, class = "Date")
> mydate
[1] "2017-01-23"
```

`mydate` is a `date`, and I want to populate the `date_of_entry` column with that `mydate` for `id == 1`. If I tried:

```
mydat$date_of_entry[mydat$id == 1] <- mydate
> mydat
  id date_of_entry
1  1         17189
2  1         17189
3  2            NA
```

However, I want the `date_of_entry` column to contain the actual date, not a numerical representation of the date in R. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `date_of_entry` column of Date class before assigning the value (currently it is of class "logical").

```
mydat$date_of_entry <- as.Date(mydat$date_of_entry)
mydat$date_of_entry[mydat$id == 1] <- mydate
mydat

#  id date_of_entry
#1  1    2017-01-23
#2  1    2017-01-23
#3  2          <NA>
```

---

Also, those numbers are numeric representation of dates so you can also convert them to dates from numbers.

```
#dataframe
mydat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2), date_of_entry = c(NA, NA, NA))
#date converted to number
mydat$date_of_entry[mydat$id == 1] <- mydate
#convert it back to date
mydat$date_of_entry <- as.Date(mydat$date_of_entry)
```